# Core Data blocks NSoperation

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have problem when I use Core Data to save data in my iOS app.

My application can receive many and many text message in a second from a server.

So i need to save those message in my data base, now i use NSOperations inside queue to save messages (so you can imagine the number of the NSOperation in the NSOperationQueue).

The problem is after some instructions, i have the NSOperationQueue blocked and the number of NSOperation increase without limit.

With some investigation I found that the problem is with the save context, the save context blocks the NSOperation and the NSOperation i will never end and it will be never dequeued,but I can't resolve it.

This my code of the NSOperation:

```
@interface SaveRecievedMessageOperation()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

@property (nonatomic, strong) AppDelegate *appdelegate;

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL executing;

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL finished;

@end

@implementation SaveRecievedMessageOperation

@synthesize message;
@synthesize managedObjectContext;
@synthesize appdelegate;
@synthesize executing;
@synthesize finished;



- (id)initWithMessage:(SipMessage *)messageToSave
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.message = messageToSave;

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)main
{

    @autoreleasepool
    {

        self.appdelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

        [self managedObjectContext];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                       selector:@selector(mergeChanges:)
                                                             name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                                           object:self.managedObjectContext];

        [self saveMessage];


    }

}

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{

    if (managedObjectContext != nil)
    {

        return managedObjectContext;

    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self.appdelegate persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
        [managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
        [managedObjectContext setMergePolicy:NSOverwriteMergePolicy];
    }
    return managedObjectContext;
}

- (void)saveMessage
{

    NSDictionary *header = self.message.headers;

    NSArray *bodies = self.message.bodies;

    SipBody *sipBody;
    NSDictionary* body;
    NSData *ContentData;
    if ([[header valueForKey:@"Content-Type"] rangeOfString:@"application/json"].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        sipBody = [bodies objectAtIndex:0];
        body = [NSJSONSerialization
                JSONObjectWithData:sipBody.content
                options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                error:nil];
    }

    else if ([[header valueForKey:@"Content-Type"] rangeOfString:@"multipart/mixed"].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        for (SipBody *sipB in bodies) {
            if ([[sipB.headers valueForKey:@"Content-Type"] rangeOfString:@"application/json"].location != NSNotFound)
            {
                body = [NSJSONSerialization
                        JSONObjectWithData:sipB.content
                        options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                        error:nil];
            }
            else
            {
                ContentData = [NSData dataWithData:sipB.content];
            }
        }
    }

    else
    {
        return;
    }
    MGMPhone *sender;

    NSArray *senders = [self updatePhonesFromMSISDNsList:[[header valueForKey:@"swfrom"] componentsSeparatedByString:MGMseparator]];
    sender = senders[0];


    NSError *error;
    MGMMessage *aMesage = [MGMMessage createInContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [aMesage setBoxType:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:BoxTypeIncomingMessage]];
    [aMesage setContent:[body valueForKey:@"Content"]];
    [aMesage setContentType:[header valueForKey:@"Content-Type"]];
    [aMesage setGroupMessage:( [[header valueForKey:@"groupmessage"] isEqualToString:@"true"]
                              ?
  [self saveContext];   
}


#pragma mark core data

- (void)mergeChanges:(NSNotification *)notification
{

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSManagedObjectContext *mainContext = [appdelegate managedObjectContext];
            [mainContext performSelector:@selector(mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:) withObject:notification];


[self setManagedObjectContext:nil];

}

- (void)saveContext
{


    NSError *error = nil;
    if (self.managedObjectContext != nil)
    {
        if ([self.managedObjectContext hasChanges]) {

            BOOL isSaved = [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
            if(!isSaved){

                NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                abort();
            }
        }
        else if (![self.managedObjectContext hasChanges]){
             [self setManagedObjectContext:nil];
        }
    }


  }


@end
```

This is a shared instance.

```
#import "CoreDataService.h"

static CoreDataService *sharedService = nil;


@implementation CoreDataService
@synthesize coreDataReceptionQueue;

+ (id)sharedService
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        if (sharedService == nil) sharedService = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedService;
}


- (NSOperationQueue*) coreDataReceptionQueue
{
    if (coreDataReceptionQueue)
    {
        return coreDataReceptionQueue;
    }
    coreDataReceptionQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [coreDataReceptionQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
    return coreDataReceptionQueue;
}
@end
```

and this how i add a new operation

```
SaveRecievedMessageOperation *op = [[SaveRecievedMessageOperation alloc]initWithMessage:message];
        [[[CoreDataService sharedService] coreDataReceptionQueue] addOperation:op];
```

Comment: show the code of NSOperationQueue

Comment: coreDataReceptionQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [coreDataReceptionQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];

Comment: where you wrote this code means in which method ?

Comment: please show your full code of queue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to read this on an iPad it's a bit difficult. It does not appear you are wrapping the messages to the moc in 'perform...' blocks - which you must do. Also, you can do the saveContext in those too. Use the asynchronous perform block for saving information and saving, and the synchronous for reading.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be an answer, but this is my observation:

1) you initialise your operation context with: `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` this will force you to use the context like so:
`[context performBlockAndWait:^{/*you code*/}]` (you use the "and wait" as you don't want your operation to finish prematurely). if you don't your operation may hang ...

==> you could use `NSConfinementConcurrencyType` and leave your code as is to resolve this

2) You use an operation queue with "max concurrency" of 1. This is infect a serial queue.
You could simply hold a single `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` context, and issue a `[context performBlock:^{/*your code*/}]` on it to achieve the same effect.